# Why doesn't "browse the complete list of questions" continue with next questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I always wonder (and find it anoying) that, when I reached the end of the first page of questions and click on "browse the complete list of questions", I find myself at the beginning of the first page of questions again.

The same happens again, if I use a smartphone and chose to view the full site.

My ideal would be to either put all those options at the top of the first page or, to continue with the next page after selection either option but that is just personal taste.

What do others think about starting with first question again after chosing either to view the complete list of questions and/or, to view the full website on a smartphone?

Comment: The complete list may include questions not visible on the front page (perhaps from downvotes, maybe for some other reason).  Although it is mildly annoying, I think the current arrangement makes the most sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say "My ideal would be to either put all those options at the top of the first page or[...]"

It seems to be like this anyway. It seems you are taking about the phrase at the end of the frontpage.

> Looking for more? Browse the [complete list of questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions), or [popular tags](https://mathoverflow.net/tags). Help us answer [unanswered questions](https://mathoverflow.net/unanswered).

The links being

- https://mathoverflow.net/questions identical to the button "Questions"
- https://mathoverflow.net/tags identical to the button "Tags"
- https://mathoverflow.net/unanswered identical to the button "Unanswered"

and thus all at the top, too.

A reason against the second idea of the request is that there really is not such a thing as "the next page" in the system that smoothly continues the list(s) on the frontpqge. One could of course completely rethink the layout of the frontpage, but then this is a bigger change than just changing the target of some links.

Comment: your link does the trick; I simply didn't see the need to press the "questions" button when I already see questions. Thanks for making me aware of the trick.